# Adding Polygon to Map in WP8 and changing Opacity/Size

Tags: dictionary, polygon, windows-phone

I'm trying to transfer a project from WP7 to WP8 (and therefore updating from Bing Maps to Nokia's builtin control).

Originally I had bounded a map region based on a whole bunch(20) of GeoCoordinates which created a MapPolygon and then changed the Opacity property of the MapPolygon before adding it as a Child to the Map Control.

As I'm trying to make the transition to Nokia's Map Control it seems to me that there is no way to specify the region of the Polygon I want created using GeoCoordinates but have to use Points instead.
Which means that as I Zoom in and out on the map the Polygon stays the same shape on the screen.
Surely there has to be a way to allow the Polygon to remain the same proportional size no matter if you zoom in/out?!?!?

I know that Bing Maps can still be used but because it is deprecated I'd rather transition to the new Nokia mapping.

Here is the code that I'm trying to use to create the new mapping:

```
//Creating a Polygon
Polygon MyPolygon = new Polygon();


MyPolygon.Points.Add(new Point(2, 0));
MyPolygon.Points.Add(new Point(22, 0));
MyPolygon.Points.Add(new Point(2, 40));
MyPolygon.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
MyPolygon.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
MyPolygon.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
MyPolygon.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
MyPolygon.Opacity = 0.5;

//Adding the Polygon to the Grid
//MyGrid.Children.Add(MyPolygon);

//Creating a MapOverlay and adding the Grid to it.
MapOverlay MyOverlay = new MapOverlay();
MyOverlay.Content = MyPolygon;

MyOverlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(49.3393850118753, -0.4569707717895518);

//MyOverlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.99, 0.99);

//Creating a MapLayer and adding the MapOverlay to it
MapLayer MyLayer = new MapLayer();
MyLayer.Add(MyOverlay);

map1.Layers.Add(MyLayer);
```

I understand that I can add the Polygon to a Grid and then the Grid to the Overlay but that still won't solve the problem.
But as you can see there is no way to add GeoCoordinates... only Points.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Surely I'm not the only one that has encountered this problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you would have to use some maths and what not but the easiest way I found was to get the coordinates of the map viewport by using **ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate** leveraging the ActualWidth and ActualHeight map properties. This was you can just get everything relative to center or whatever math you want to use to keep proportion.

You can also use a **MapPolyline** for drawing which will take GeoCoordinates.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.mappolyline.aspx

You should be covered in almost any scenario then.

Hope that helps???

// Jed